# How many items sold each hour for each UID?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a products table with the below structure (limited to 10 rows)

```
 UID                                      Time           Name Total_Amount
('a63d7d52-0fa8-4d56-b954-a9ecb86e350a', 1599887740389, 'test',1.9)
('a63d7d52-0fa8-4d56-b954-a9ecb86e350a', 1599887740390, 'test 1',1.9)
('b63d7d52-0fa8-4d56-b954-a9ecb86e350a', 1599887740391, 'test 2',2.1)
('b63d7d52-0fa8-4d56-b954-a9ecb86e350a', 1599887740392, 'test 3',2.3)
('c63d7d52-0fa8-4d56-b954-a9ecb86e350a', 1599887740393, 'test 4',3.5)
('c63d7d52-0fa8-4d56-b954-a9ecb86e350a', 1599887740394, 'test 5',4.9)
('d63d7d52-0fa8-4d56-b954-a9ecb86e350a', 1599887740395, 'test 6',5.3)
('d63d7d52-0fa8-4d56-b954-a9ecb86e350a', 1599887740396, 'test 7',6.7)
('e63d7d52-0fa8-4d56-b954-a9ecb86e350a', 1599887740397, 'test 8',8.1)
('e63d7d52-0fa8-4d56-b954-a9ecb86e350a', 1599887740398, 'test 9',9.7)
```

I need to write a query to find out "How many items were sold for each hour of the day for each UID?"

I tried

```
SELECT UID,time,count(total_amount) from products group by UID,Time
```

but this just outputs the list, How can I get a count of how many items were sold of each UID for each hour?

Comment: can you please tag the database you are using? every tdms has it own functions

Comment: @nbk Apologies, using SQlite. Have added the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your time looks like unix milliseconds. Try

```
select UID, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H',time/1000, 'unixepoch') h, count(total_amount) 
from products 
group by UID, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H',time/1000, 'unixepoch')
```

Comment: minus the epoch, thats not any different to my query? How do I get the total items sold for each UID?

Comment: Why 'start of month'?

Answer (score 0):

You can strip minutes and seconds from the timestamps if you divide by 3600000 and multiply by 3600, and then aggregate per product and hour:

```
SELECT UID, 
       datetime(Time / 3600000 * 3600, 'unixepoch') hour,
       SUM(Total_Amount) Total_Amount
FROM products
GROUP BY UID, hour;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=200cc315cb4310f6a8111650d7a4c39d).